# How do users know submit was successful if javascript not enabled?

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I'm in a weird situation.  I just found out that near 50% of my users don't have javascript enabled.  Most of my website is based on a lengthy search function.  Once users click submit, the function executes, and we send them an email when it's finished - this can sometimes take up to 10 minutes.

My issue is that I don't know how to tell users the button was clicked successfully to start this long function if they have javascript disabled.  Any ideas?

Comment: The usual way is to refresh their page with new content.  Why can't you do this?

Comment: Because the next page won't load until the entire php function executes.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Errrr, without Javascript why not just redirect to a temporary page (and redirect back if you must) that lets them know the status then you the function can execute?

Comment: @Bob Cavezza:  "Is there a way around this?" Yes. Don't do the *entire* thing in the PHP code supporting the page.  This "background" function has to actually run in the actual background.

Comment: @S.Lott How would I do this?  Create a temp cron job in php?

Comment: @Pete I was looking at Curl functions, haven't been able to find an auto submit function that takes the user back to the resulting code, That's what I'm in the middle of testing, though

Comment: @Bob Cavezza, for delayed tasks this module can be used: https://github.com/jamm/Tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once submitted, spawn a php process that does the search and return immediately with the page saying the job was submitted.

The php reference talks about this, with a comment stating that you would call the process using nohup so that it doesn't die when the caller returns.
[php.net exec function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: This looks perfect - Just need to figure out how to send post data

Answer (score 1):

As an idea: if you can detect, that some users don't have javascript enabled, maybe for that users you will show page without javascript, html with simple 'type="submit"' button?

Comment: I'm in the middle of building the non-javascript site now.  I'm trying to find a way to show them that they correctly pressed the submit button.  There is a type="submit" button, the next page doesn't load until the entire php in that next page finishes executing

Comment: well... long, but more smart way: create task, which will be executed separately, by script from 'cron'. And open page, which will be reloads each 5 seconds and check, if task has executed (check for existing file with results or key in memcache with results). And write at this page: "In progress..." (or something more smart). And when result will be fetched, you'll be able to show data for user on another page. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

you can check it on server side... when the form is sent to server just check if the submit button value is set.

Comment: Yes, but how do I relay a message in the browser that the submit button was clicked?  - My issue is usability and telling users that their action was done successfully, so they don't press the submit button 4 times, think nothing happened, then exit.